# Sharing Internet Connection

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have two computers connected via LAN network , one of them has internet connection , How can I access the internet from the another computer using the connection in the first one ?  Both computers are running on windows 7 os. the first one has wired modem connection.

Comment: If they are both connected "communicating" via LAN but only one has internet... where is the one getting internet from?

Comment: How are those computers communicating between each other? Via Switch? Or are the connected directly? Does one PC have a WiFi abilities and that is how connects to the Internet? There is so many endless possibilities....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the underlying networks are both sound and in working order, all that need be done is to open the properties dialog of the network connection you wish to share.  Click on the share tab, and select enable connection sharing.  Depending on the 2 networks, and their IP ranges you may have to set some static addresses.  let us know if you have any issues.